# Divide list of coordinates into a grid

Tags: c#, loops, coordinates

I have list of evenly distributed coordinates which goes like this:

```
0,0
0.1,0
0.2,0
n,0
0,0.1
0.1,0.1
0.2,0.1
n,0.1
0,m
0.1,m
0.2,m
n,m
```

First value is X, second value is Y.
n is a parameter that represents max X (length of a coordinade set)
m is max Y (height of a coordinate set)

This set is a List of lists. It holds n*m points. Each point holds 2 values.

I want to cluster them into smaller grids. Grid length and heigth should be a variable.

Comment: What do `b` and `m` represent

Comment: length and width of a full coordinate set

Comment: you can't cluster the cells into an (p x q) sized grids unless p (the width) is a factor of n and q is a factor of m, otherwise there will be incomplete grids. you have to specify the exact behavior that you want as well as the input and output formats.